# How to show the field generated by $3^{\frac{2}{3^5-1}} \cdot \zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is same as $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, extension-field

Consider the polynomial $p(x)=3^{3^3+1}x-x^{3^5}$ over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.

The solutions of $p(x)$ are given by $r_{n}:=\zeta^n \cdot 3^{\frac{3^3+1}{3^5-1}},~0 \leq n \leq 3^5-2$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $3^5-1$ root of $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let us denote $K:=\mathbb{Q}[r_{0},r_{1},r_{2}, \dots, r_{3^5-2}]$.

> I want to show the field generated by $3^{\frac{2}{3^5-1}} \cdot \zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is same as $K$.

**Edit:**

To make the context clear, let us consider another polynomial $q(x)=3^{3^2+1}x-x^{3^5}$ over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.
The solutions of $q(x)$ are given by $s_{n}:=\zeta^n \cdot 3^{\frac{3^2+1}{3^5-1}},~0 \leq n \leq 3^5-2$, where $\zeta$ be a primitive $3^5-1$ root of $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let us denote $L:=\mathbb{Q}[s_{0},s_{1},s_{2}, \dots, s_{3^5-2}]$.

My purpose is to show $K=L$ by showing that both $K$ and $L$ are generated by same element over $\mathbb{Q}$ and that element is $3^{\frac{2}{3^5-1}} \cdot \zeta$.

This is why I asked my previous question.

Is there other way to show $K=L$ ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132662/discussion-on-question-by-mathlearner-how-to-show-the-field-generated-by-3-fr).